# How to access nested optional indexes from interface

Tags: typescript

Given the following interface described on [this TS playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiwYBVgGcYCWAthAHYECGANrgMrADGhZAigK7BSJwC8cA3nABQcOAH0xSFKQpFgAfgBccAOTtOiFQBphomHkIly1Oo2aklA3aPGTkwGXMsqc+YmUo16TAmW3XRAgATZXwoAlIAcx0RG303I09cZQBBKCgKRAAeQQkpB1kFZRcDd2Mqf2DQmHConX0QGGra6LgKNhgAC2hLXLtpQudXQw9qFI7uqEqQuDCI1sdgZvmdMG6YCGU+-MXnFNxcTH82KCplqLgAXyu4AB84UjYqKiuAPmFr+8fnq4BuISE+TgwzKSV46EwIMSJm85nUXAA2ip4iNyqYfH4ALpIlGgkwqTFAA)

```
export type GetTestimonialsSectionQuery = { 
  __typename?: 'Query', 
  testimonialsSection?: { 
    __typename?: 'TestimonialsSection', 
    id: string, 
    testimonials: Array<{ __typename?: 'Testimonial', id: string, text: string, author?: { __typename?: 'TestimonialAuthor', id: string, name: string, photo: { __typename?: 'Asset', url: string } } | null }> 
} | null };
```

I would like to access the `testimonials` index from the whole interface [by using the indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), however, it doesn't work when the `strictNullChecks` compiler option is set and the result is `any`

Since `testimonials` can be `undefined`, would a type check needed before accessing the nested property?

Comment: [Please replace or supplement images of code/text with plaintext versions directly in the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).

Comment: You could use [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to remove `null` and `undefined` from a type before you index into it, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEv52N).  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, good catch! If you could write that as the answer, would be nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only perform an indexed access of the form `T[K]` when `K` is definitely a key type for `K`; that is, when `K extends keyof T`.  If `T` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) then the only definite keys of `T` are those keys present on every member of the union.  That is, `keyof (A | B | C)` becomes `(keyof A) & (keyof B) & (keyof C)`.

In your case, since `GetTestimonialsSectionQuery['testimonialsSection']` is a union of an object type with both `null` and `undefined`, you won't be allowed to index into it with anything that isn't also a key of `null` and `undefined`... and `null` and `undefined` have no keys; you can't index into them at all.  Hence the error:

```
type Bad = GetTestimonialsSectionQuery[
    'testimonialsSection']['testimonials'] // error!
// ----------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'testimonials' does not exist on type ...
```

If all you care about is the object type and not the `null` and `undefined`, you can use a utility type to filter the union to just the object type before indexing into it.  In general, you can filter unions via [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion), but for the specific and common case of removing `null` and `undefined`, you can use [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype):

```
type Testimonials = NonNullable<
    GetTestimonialsSectionQuery['testimonialsSection']
>['testimonials']
/* type Testimonials = {
    __typename?: "Testimonial" | undefined;
    id: string;
    text: string;
    author?: {
        __typename?: "TestimonialAuthor" | undefined;
        id: string;
        name: string;
        photo: {
            __typename?: 'Asset';
            url: string;
        };
    } | null | undefined;
}[] */
type Testimonials = NonNullable<
    GetTestimonialsSectionQuery['testimonialsSection']
>['testimonials']
/* type Testimonials = {
    __typename?: "Testimonial" | undefined;
    id: string;
    text: string;
    author?: {
        __typename?: "TestimonialAuthor" | undefined;
        id: string;
        name: string;
        photo: {
            __typename?: 'Asset';
            url: string;
        };
    } | null | undefined;
}[] */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)